# How to make Ktor's Application.module() work in GraalVM

Tags: kotlin, ktor, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to get started with Ktor and GraalVM. I am trying to run a very dummy Ktor app (IntelliJ's default one) with GraalVM.

I've followed https://ktor.io/docs/graalvm.html#prepare-for-graalvm steps and it is working fine because it configures routing directly from the `embeddedServer` call.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(CIO, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
        configureRouting()
    }.start(wait = true)

}
```

However, when I refactored this code to:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(CIO, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0", module = Application::module)
        .start(wait = true)
}

fun Application.module() {
    configureRouting()
}
```

it stopped working. The error is a reflection issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: Could not compute caller for function: public fun io.ktor.server.application.Application.module(): kotlin.Unit defined in xxxxx[DeserializedSimpleFunctionDescriptor@2ab47469] (member = null)
```

I've tried a lot of different things in my `reflect-config.json` file, that actually looks like:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectionFactoryImpl",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "mypackage.Application",
    "methods": [
      {
        "name": "module",
        "parameterTypes": [],
        "returnType": "kotlin.Unit"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "io.ktor.server.application.Application",
    "methods": [
      {
        "name": "module",
        "parameterTypes": [],
        "returnType": "kotlin.Unit"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "mypackage.plugins.Routing",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "kotlin.KotlinVersion",
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  },
  {
    "name": "kotlin.KotlinVersion[]"
  },
  {
    "name": "kotlin.KotlinVersion$Companion"
  },
  {
    "name": "kotlin.KotlinVersion$Companion[]"
  },
  {
    "name": "kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations",
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true
  }
]
```

my file structure for the project looks like

```
src/main
├── kotlin
│   └── mypackage
│       ├── Application.kt
│       └── plugins
│           └── Routing.kt
└── resources
    ├── META-INF
    │   └── native-image
    │       └── reflect-config.json
    └── logback.xml
```

where `Application.kt` looks like the previous code and `Routing.kt` is just:

```kotlin
fun Application.configureRouting() {
    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hello World!")
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the code works when configuring the routing directly on the `embeddedServer` but delegating in the `Application.module()` function is way more convenient and mantainable.

If anyone can provide any feedback, it would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try running your app with agent enabled, then compiling it using `reflect-config.json` created by the agent. If it works, you might want to compare the two configs to see the difference. My guess it would be some reflective call deep inside the framework that's missing from your config.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @peterz but may I ask what do you mean by `agent enabled` . I am not sure I follow, thanks!

Comment: https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/Agent/

Answer (score 0):

In order to build ktor with graalvm you need to run agent like below

```bash
java -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=./graalcnf/ -jar target/ktor-demo-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

This will generate reflect json and other files under graalcnf folder, then you need to provide those in native-image.properties as argument like below

```bash
Args = --enable-http \
-H:IncludeResources=.*\\.properties \
  -H:ConfigurationFileDirectories=${project.basedir}/graalcnf/
```

I did this couple of years ago for my test framework which is comparing multiple microservice frameworks like spring quarkus etc. You can reach the example code [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/test-microservice-frameworks/blob/main/ktor-demo/resources/META-INF/native-image/com.mascix/ktor-demo/native-image.properties) and you can see some comparison at [here](https://ozkanpakdil.github.io/microservicetests/2023-11-01-microservice-framework-test-20.html)